# How to show characters in different font in Text Widget Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, text, tiktok

My app fetches data from TikTok through a Api. The username and caption of some TikToks contains some special characters and fonts like: ℋℒℰ and some contains text in other languages. When I tested the Api on its website it show the data correct
[image]

but when I get that data through my app it changes the special characters and language to something like this

ÐÐµ ÑÐ¾ÑÐµÐ»Ð° Ð¸Ð³ÑÐ°ÑÑ Ñ Ð±Ð°ÑÐ½Ð¸ÑÑÐ¾Ð¼ ÐÐµÐ»Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð»ÐµÐ¿Ð½Ð°Ñ ÑÐºÑÐ¸Ð¿Ð°ÑÐºÐ°!

and other values or links that is in english dose not change

The code am using is

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
  "X-RapidAPI-Host":
      "tiktok-downloader-download-tiktok-videos-without-watermark.p.rapidapi.com",
  "X-RapidAPI-Key": "-------------------------------",
};

final body = {'url': url};
final uri = Uri.https(
    "tiktok-downloader-download-tiktok-videos-without-watermark.p.rapidapi.com",
    '/vid/index',
    body);
final response = await http.get(
  uri,
  headers: headers,
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  print(data['description'][0]);
}
```

The Api am using

https://rapidapi.com/maatootz/api/tiktok-downloader-download-tiktok-videos-without-watermark

Answer (score 1):

As I've tested your strings in live demo of **TextField**, Its showing me perfectly. I think you may have to checked it by copy/paste same string in your TextField.

Here is the output

[image]

Here is the link to test it by yourself: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-input

Tryout with simple TextField widget first if you are using any custom widget.

Comment: Yeah you are right the problem is with api. I am changing the question please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a display issue, you might be using a font which does not have Glyphs for the languages you are trying to display. Try changing your app font to something which is widely used and covers most of the languages like `Roboto`. You can go to Google fonts, choose a font and copy/paste your text e.g. [This is how your text will appear with Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?preview.text=%D0%9D%D0%B5%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC!%20%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0&preview.text_type=custom)

To add Google fonts to your App you can use [google_fonts package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts)

If it is not display issue rather on API side then make sure the API is working with proper mime and file types e.g. UTF8